# Using the value of a variable in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Can anyone help me to create a map using dynamic variable value as a key in XSLT 1.0

I have a variable `addressID` whose value is 123. I would like to use this as a key in a map

```
<xsl:value-of select="$addressID" /> // gives output 123

<my:map>
  <entry key="$addressID">1</entry>
</my:map>
```

Please suggest me the proper syntax to use a variable in key.

Answer (score 3):

First, setup variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="addressID">123</xsl:variable>
```

Second, you can use it as follow:

```
<my:map>
  <entry key="{$addressID}">1</entry>
</my:map>
```

via http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#variables

Comment: Here's another link that might help: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates You can also declare your variable using `select` to avoid creating an unnecessary tree: `<xsl:variable name="test" select="'123'"/>`

Answer (score 0):

CodeGroover is right, and you can also use `attribute`
 provided example below

```
<my:map>
  <entry>
    <xsl:attribute name="key">
       <xsl:value-of select="$addressID"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="'1'"/>
  </entry>
</my:map>
```